# iOS Is there any limitation of white space number in sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode?

Tags: ios, nsstring, sizewithfont

I'm making chatting App on iPhone. 
I have a problem with sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode function.
When NSString has a long length white space, sizeWithFont() always return (width:218, height:18)

This is my test code.

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    [string insertString:@" " atIndex:0];
    NSInteger length = string.length;
    CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"Text:%@\nlength: %d\nsize: %f, %f\n",string, length, size.width, size.height, nil);
}
```

And this is result.

```
Text: 
length: 1
size: 4.000000, 18.000000
Text:  
length: 2
size: 8.000000, 18.000000
Text:   
length: 3
size: 12.000000, 18.000000
.
.
.
Text:                                                        
length: 56
size: 218.000000, 18.000000
Text:                                                         
length: 57
size: 218.000000, 18.000000
Text:                                                          
length: 58
.
.
.
Text:                                                                                                   
length: 99
size: 218.000000, 18.000000
```

Question: How can I get the right size of long white space string?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and there are no words.

Try using `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.

Comment: I tried to test 'NSLineBreakByCharWrapping'. The result is same.